# Xcode Storyboard - UITableViewCell UISwitch Value Changed

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard, uiswitch

I have am using Xcode storyboards and have a View Controller that has a UITableView which in turn has a custom UITableViewCell.

The UITableViewCell has a UISwitch in it and I want to know when the value has changed. I have a IBAction that successfully fires when the value is changed

```
- (IBAction)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSLog(@"In SettingsViewcontroller updateSwitchAtIndexPath row=|%d \n", indexPath.row);
}
```

However when it fires the app terminates

```
2014-07-10 23:38:10.037 reactor[2572:60b] -[UISwitch row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x944b7e0
2014-07-10 23:38:10.072 reactor[2572:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISwitch row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x944b7e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a281e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015758e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ac5243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275   
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a1850b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a180ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   positivity                          0x00003807 -[SettingsViewController updateSwitchAtIndexPath:] + 87
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0158782b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    7   UIKit                               0x002373b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    8   UIKit                               0x00237345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    9   UIKit                               0x00338bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    10  UIKit                               0x00338fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    11  UIKit                               0x004c97a5 __31-[UISwitch _handleLongPressNL:]_block_invoke + 85
    12  UIKit                               0x004c8666 -[_UISwitchInternalViewNeueStyle1 _setPressed:on:animated:shouldAnimateLabels:completion:] + 243
    13  UIKit                               0x004c9681 -[UISwitch _handleLongPressNL:] + 286
    14  UIKit                               0x005d14f4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
    15  UIKit                               0x005d0168 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
    16  UIKit                               0x005d1bdd -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    17  UIKit                               0x005d513d ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
    18  UIKit                               0x005d50be _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    19  UIKit                               0x005cb7ac _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
    20  UIKit                               0x00276a5a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    21  UIKit                               0x00277971 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    22  UIKit                               0x002495f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    23  UIKit                               0x00233353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x019b177f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x019b110b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x019ce1ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x019cd9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x019cd7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x03a1c5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x03a1c42b GSEventRun + 104
    31  UIKit                               0x00235f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    32  positivity                          0x00005dbd main + 141
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x0206f701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

UISwitch does not have a property called "row." The way your IBOutlet is set up, you will actually get an UISwitch object as a parameter instead of NSIndexPath.

The better thing to do here is to use the delegate pattern. That way, the custom cell can notify the UIViewController (containing the UITableView) that the switch has been pressed.

So it would be more like:

```
- (IBAction)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(UISwitch *)mySwitch
{
    // notify the delegate about the switch update
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(switchWasPressed:)]) {
        [self.delegate switchWasPressed:mySwitch];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but how do I tell which row was selected ?

Comment: Technically, you didn't select a row. Why do you want to know which row was selected? You already know which cell contains the UISwitch.

Comment: How do I know that? Each row has a uiswitch.

Comment: OK, that's helpful. I don't see where that was made clear in your original post. There are definitely a few things you could do. One would be to subclass UISwitch and have it keep a reference to the cell to which it belongs (as a property). You will then be able to access the cell via the delegate method described above.